# Separate SSD exclusively for Ubuntu on a Windows Machine

Tags: partitioning, windows-10, boot-partition

The title might not be enough to explain my problem, so I will try to explain it briefly:

I have a Windows Computer and built in a new SSD, which I want to install Ubuntu on, and nothing else.

There are a bunch of tutorials, threads, and of course Stackexchange questions, yet I feel they all miss a couple of small steps, refer to another tutorial/thread or somehow show different (outdated?) screens than my installation process

So far I have formatted the ssd to ext4 and created a bootable usb drive with rufus.
I set the correct boot priority and the Ubuntu installer commences.

Now, when I enter the step where the options are.
"Install alongside Windows"
"Erase disk and install Ubuntu"
"Something else"

I am unsure on what to choose.

"Install alongside Windows"
only gives me the slider option on how I want to partition the disk between Ubuntu and what's the other partition? The bootloader that will give me the option on what os to boot?
Does that mean my boot priority would have to be that specific ssd i installed Ubuntu on?
Or can I install a bootloader on my main m.2 windows os ssd and refer to the secondary ssd with Ubuntu on it?
How would that work?

"Erase disk and install Ubuntu"
sounds highly dangerous and I am afraid to do it, also I don't fully understand the partition table.

"Something else"
Was mentioned in one tutorial as it's supposed to give me more control over the partitions, yet since I'm already confused with the other ones I don't want to just try it out since obviously I don't want to lose my data :)

I hope this post isn't too clattered

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? Is SSD shown correctly? What brand/model system? UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Others suggest disconnecting all other drives physically or logically in UEFI settings, so install drive is first drive. Or removing boot flag/esp flag from first drive, so ESP is install drive.

Comment: Unplu the Windows disk before proceeding. Install Ubuntu in the same BIOS/UEFI mode as Windows. When install complete run `sudo update-grub` to add Wwindows to the new grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose both Erase Disk and install ubuntu and Something else.

"**Erase Disk and install ubuntu**" is an easy step where you don't have to define filetypes and partion.

"**Something Else**"=> if you choose this option you have to define partition yourself and filesystem to.

I prefer you to install using "**Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu**". You can choose the drive like this:

[image]

Comment: Alright thank you,  and how do I choose from which disk I will boot? All from the bios / uefi? Can I install a boot manager on my main windows drive?

Comment: you said you format SSD right?

Comment: if you choose Erase disk and install Ubuntu, it will format the disk and install Ubuntu only, without any problem

Comment: yes you can install on your windows drive. If you don't want to use windows anymore.

Comment: I still want to use windows on my first and primary ssd. I just don't want to go in the uefi every time I want to switch os

Comment: do you have 2 SSD?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes I have two ssd. One with windows I want to keep. One I want to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115530/discussion-between-ghimires-and-hanzolo).

Comment: Try Erase disk and install ubuntu. Go one step further. It should give you option on which disk to install. If it don't give you any option click back.
and let me know

Comment: It does give me the option, hold on a minute, I had to go away from the computer, I will be right back

Comment: I have updated my post have a look once.